# Trying to build PLJAVA 1.5.6 on java 8 + enterprisedb 15.2 fails

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, enterprisedb, pljava

Modified the Changes for PLJAVA 1.5.6 since we cannot update the java version to 9 . but now linker is failing while i do the mvn clean install . doing the mvn command from microsoft visual studio command prompt as suggested in installation side

```
[INFO] Timestamp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] Timestamp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] TupleTable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] TupleTable.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] JNICalls.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] JNICalls.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] PgObject.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] PgObject.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] PgSavepoint.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] PgSavepoint.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] Portal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] Portal.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] ExecutionPlan.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] ExecutionPlan.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] Function.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] Function.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] InstallHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] InstallHelper.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] Invocation.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] Invocation.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] AclId.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] AclId.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] Backend.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] Backend.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] Composite.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] Composite.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] Exception.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[ERROR] Exception.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _errstart
[INFO] Type.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _errfinish referenced in function _Type_fromJavaType
[ERROR] Type.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _errfinish referenced in function _Type_fromJavaType
```

Tried installing but kept on failing no luck so far

Comment: Documentation says "No version of Java before 9 is supported. The PL/Java code makes use of Java features first appearing in Java 9.". Why do you believe this should work with Java 8?

Comment: @aled https://github.com/tada/pljava/releases java 8 to 9 was done in pl java 1.6.0 below that it was supported with java8

Answer (score 0):

The error messages show failure at link time to find certain symbols inside PostgreSQL, `_errstart` and `_errfinish`. Those are important.

The question title mentions EnterpriseDB, which might be a clue. There was another issue reported not long ago where they had made some internal change in their version of PostgreSQL, making it impossible for PL/Java to link to the expected PostgreSQL API. I do not have details of anything they might have done involving `_errstart` and `_errfinish`, but it is hard to think of many other explanations for just those two symbols being unlinkable. If you were missing the PostgreSQL development files, there would be more than just two things missing.